# Пытаюсь сделать splash screen, но оно ломает мне проект и сама не показывается в Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

Задача сделать SplashScreen как в ютубе/вконтакте и других приложениях. Но оно не показывается и в процессе она сломала мне ImageSwitcher из активити и она больше не показывает никаких картинок.
Я следовал этим статьям и я не знаю что я не так сделал:

1. [#1](https://shishirthedev.medium.com/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a)
2. [#2](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/345380/)
3. [#3](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/312516/)

Я пробовал каждый из вариантов, но либо оно не запускается, либо не показывается.

- Вот моя разметка:

---

- background_splash.xml, тут указана сама тема

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <!-- Цвет фона, предпочтительно как в главной теме -->

    <!-- Лого приложения - 144dp версия иконки приложения -->
    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

посередине стоит значок приложения, а в заднем фоне должен быть задний фон, но я ее убрал когда пытался отладить.

- и в styles.xml моя тема объявляется под именем AppTheme.Launcher:

  ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
   <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
   </style>
  ```
- в манифесте указана моя тема на intent-filter

  ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.InSport">
       <activity android:name=".ChatOneToOne"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".MsgCenter" />
       <activity android:name=".addToTeam" />
       <activity android:name=".inTeam" />
       <activity android:name=".Team" />
       <activity android:name=".ShowTurnirs" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.Info" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.friendsRequest" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.training" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.EnemyProfile" />
       <activity android:name=".findtest" />
       <activity
           android:name=".Sign.LoadFrame"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".Sign.BackFrame" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.ProfileEdit" />
       <activity android:name=".Profile.Friends" />
       <activity
           android:name=".HomeNav"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_home_nav"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.InSport.NoActionBar" />
       <activity android:name=".Sign.SignUp" />
       <activity android:name=".Sign.SignIn" />
   </application>
  ```
- а дальше в LoadActivity, в первом активити которое запускается в OnCreate указана основная тема согласно статье:

  ```
   public class LoadFrame extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ImageSwitcher mImageSwitcher;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setTheme(R.style.Theme_InSport);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.load_frame);
       getSupportActionBar().hide();
       FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
       if (user != null){
           startActivity(new Intent(LoadFrame.this, HomeNav.class));
           finish();
       }
       mImageSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
       Animation inAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
       inAnimation.setDuration(1000);
       Animation outAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
       outAnimation.setDuration(1000);

       mImageSwitcher.setInAnimation(inAnimation);
       mImageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(outAnimation);
       //cw.setOnClickListener(v -> );

       if (user == null) {
           Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                       mImageSwitcher.postDelayed(runn1, 1000);
                       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                       runOnUiThread(runn2);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
           t.start();
       }
   }

   Runnable runn1 = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           mImageSwitcher.showNext();
       }
   };

   Runnable runn2 = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           startActivity(new Intent(LoadFrame.this, BackFrame.class));
       }
   };


   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //startActivity(new Intent(LoadFrame.this, BackFrame.class));
                   /*new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           startActivity(new Intent(LoadFrame.this, BackFrame.class));
                       }
                   });*/

           }
       }, 2000);


      /* Handler end;
       end = new Handler();
       end.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

           }
       }, 3000);*/
   }
  }
  ```

Если что то не понятно обращайтесь пожалуйста ибо я и сам не понимаю что не так

Comment: может нужно без ActionBar'а? `<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: @IR42 попробовал, по прежнему ничего не отображает. Попробую создать отдельный класс для сплэщ скрин как на первой статье. Может я что то не так сделал

Comment: Вам стиль надо указывать не у активити, но у приложения. Т.е. в тэге `application` в манифесте

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет тоже не показывает, а еще крашит при повторном запуске loadActivity из приложения. Это наверное происходит из за того что в onCreate, я установил setTheme стандартную тему

Comment: Если падает - надо логи прикладывать и место падения - причин может быть много.